# Prevent drupal_messages in drush

Tags: drush, status-messages

I am creating a bash script to automate some stuff including drush commands. When using drush vget I always get Drupal messages, but I only want the value of the variable. This prevents me from correctly using the drush vget output. I already tried with output formats etc. but I always get the messages. How to prevent the Drupal messages to use the output of drush vget in my shell script?

Comment: What sort of messages? Errors/warnings? The variable output should be on the last line, should be easy to parse that

Comment: In my case warnings. But I just realized they are just printed to the command line and are not contained in the return value itself. So it is actually working. Since I was printing my variable directly for debugging it looked like it contained the messages as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized they are just printed to the command line and are not contained in the return value itself. So it is actually working. Since I was printing my variable directly for debugging it looked like it contained the messages as well.